# make Tab key do 4 space instead 8 in textbox tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, key

I'm trying to create a text editor with tkinter
When I click on the Tab key on the keyboard it does 8 spaces I want it to do only 4 spaces instead of 8
code:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.title('Text editor')

text = tk.Text(root)
text.pack()


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: When you say "it does", do you mean you want it to literally insert 4 spaces, or do you want it to insert a tab that is four spaces wide?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```py
import tkinter as tk

def tab_pressed(event:tk.Event) -> str:
    # Insert the 4 spaces
    text.insert("insert", " "*4)
    # Prevent the default tkinter behaviour
    return "break"

root = tk.Tk()

text = tk.Text(root)
text.pack()
text.bind("<Tab>", tab_pressed)

root.mainloop()
```

I used `.bind` and `return "break"` to add my own functionality for when the tab key is pressed while blocking tkinter's default behaviour.

If you just want the tabs to be 4 spaces wide, look [here](https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/python/how+to+set+the+tab+size+in+tkinter).

Answer (score 1):

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.font as tkfont

root = Tk()

text = Text(root)
text.pack()

font = tkfont.Font(font=text["font"])

tab_width = font.measure(" " * 4)
text.config(tabs=tab_width)

root.mainloop()
```

`tab_width = font.measure(" " * 4)` just sets tabs to be 4 spaces, then `text.config(tabs=tab_width)` applies that change to the textbox `text`.

Hope this helps mate, cheers!

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and/or *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.